# How do i fix following js so that on scroll there wont be any fluctuating effects in animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onscroll

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >0 && $(window).scrollTop() <720) {
    $('.terminator-text').animate({left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug1').animate({ left: '14%' ,top:'16%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug2').animate({ left: '73%',top:'20%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug3').animate({ left: '21%',top:'70%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug4').animate({ left: '65%',top:'46%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug5').animate({ left: '17%',top:'40%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug6').animate({ left: '53%',top:'69%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug7').animate({ left: '58%',top:'52%',opacity:'1'});
  }
  else {
    $('.terminator-text').animate({left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'0'});
    $('.bug1').animate({ left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'0'});
    $('.bug2').animate({ left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'0'});
    $('.bug3').animate({ left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'0'});
    $('.bug4').animate({ left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'0'});
    $('.bug5').animate({ left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'0'});
    $('.bug6').animate({ left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'0'});
    $('.bug7').animate({ left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'0'});
   }
});

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >720 ) {
    $('.bug1').animate({ left: '5%' ,top:'8%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug2').animate({ left: '80%',top:'10%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug3').animate({ left: '12%',top:'78%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug4').animate({ left: '77%',top:'48%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug5').animate({ left: '5%',top:'53%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug6').animate({ left: '58%',top:'77%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug7').animate({ left: '68%',top:'59%',opacity:'1'});
  }
  else {
    $('.terminator-text').animate({left: '50%',top:'50%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug1').animate({ left: '14%' ,top:'16%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug2').animate({ left: '73%',top:'20%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug3').animate({ left: '21%',top:'70%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug4').animate({ left: '65%',top:'46%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug5').animate({ left: '17%',top:'40%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug6').animate({ left: '53%',top:'69%',opacity:'1'});
    $('.bug7').animate({ left: '58%',top:'52%',opacity:'1'});
  }
});
```

Main issue occuring in

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >720
```

this condition how do I fix it to get it resolved ang get smooth transition

Comment: Style Css for the above bugs


.bug1 ,.bug2 ,.bug3 ,.bug4 ,.bug5 ,.bug6 ,.bug7 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
 
}

Comment: Can you give us a live link to see the effects? Or maybe a jsfiddle ?

Comment: You've bound two `scroll` event handlers. In first `event` handler you are checking the condition `if ($(window).scrollTop() >0 && $(window).scrollTop() <720) {` and there is an else statement. In second also you checking `if ($(window).scrollTop() >720 ) {` and it has an else statement. I guess both the event handlers are triggering simultaneously and modifying the DOM that's why you're getting the flickering. Put both together inside one event handler and use `if, else if, else` condition. Another option would be to use `window.requestAnimationFrame` to optimize animation

Comment: http://demo.tecmerch.com/pidilite/scroll/

see the effects here